# ubercart 3 Restrict total cart quantity amount needed to checkout (e.g. no more than 8 bulk bags)

Tags: php, drupal-7, ubercart

I am trying to accomplish a task in Drupal 7 with Ubercart 3.
The task is to Restrict total cart quantity amount needed to checkout (e.g. no more than 8 bulk bags). This applies only to few items, where if item 1 is 8, do not allow to add more items(which have the max of 8 bulk bags as well) but allow to add other items.
Item 1 have max quantity of 8 and item2 as well. In the cart if item1 have 5 then allow to add 3items to item2 or item3.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The restriction will be to a total amount of products in cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used custom module, where I have restricted the add to cart and update cart.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the code/steps to implement the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubercart Product Minimum & Maximum may fit your needs. Enables per-product minimums and maximums on add to cart cart and on checkout:

http://drupal.org/project/uc_product_minmax

Comment: Yeah ive got that module installed, but only limits one product in the cart, not a bulk of products. I need a restriction for products where the maximum allowed quantity is lets say 8, but this quantity will be limited to item 1+item2 in the cart

Comment: been trying to expand the code but not sure how to get the nid of items from cart, which have the maximum restriction

Comment: anyways sorted with my custom module, which will be commited to drupal.org community.